# I want to add the comma at the end of the string in javascript in Fibonacci series

Tags: javascript

I have to create a Javascript program for a Fibonacci series, and following are the conditions:

1. Every number should be separated by a comma.
2. Method should check for valid values and return -1 (number) for integers less than 1, non numeric values.
3. Returned value should always be string for valid input passed.
4. Output string should end with a comma.

I have done the first 3 steps but stuck in the last one. Unable to understand that how can I add comma at the end of the series. Because if I define sum+= sum + ',', then the first time 11,2,3 is printed with no comma between the first 2 numbers.

```js
function fibonacci(len) {
  var a = 0,
    b = 1,
    f = 1,
    sum = 1;
  if (len > 2) {
    for (var i = 2; i <= len; i++) {
      f = a + b;
      sum += ',' + f;
      a = b;
      b = f;
    }
  } else if (len == 1) {
    sum = '1,1,';
  } else {
    sum = '-1';
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(fibonacci(10))
```

Comment: `return sum+",";` Or use push and don't use commas until the end

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `return sum+",";`

I suggest you use an array and join. Also get rid of duff data at the start

Also loop from 1

```js
function fibonacci(len) {
  if (isNaN(len) || len < 1 ) return -1;
  let a = 0, b = 1, f = 1, sum = [1];
  for (let i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    f = a + b;
    sum.push(f);
    a = b;
    b = f;
  }
  return sum === -1 ? sum : sum.join(",") + ",";
}

// tests
console.log(fibonacci(10))
console.log(fibonacci(1))
console.log(fibonacci(2))
console.log(fibonacci(0))
console.log(fibonacci("A"))
console.log(fibonacci("    1    "))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fibonacci(len) {
    // check if valid length
    if(isNaN(len) || (parseInt(len) | 0) !== len || len < 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    // initialize starting value
    var sequences = [1, 1];
    var current = 1;
    for(let i = 1; i<len; i++) {
        // sum last 2 sequence
        var x = sequences[i] + sequences[i-1];
        sequences.push(x);
    }
    // join with comma
    return sequences.join(", ") + ",";
}

console.log(fibonacci(1))
console.log(fibonacci(5))
console.log(fibonacci("a"))
```